# Identical syntax that has different semantics between C/C++

Tags: c++, c, semantics

What are examples of syntax that is valid in both C and C++ but has different semantics? Put another way, what are examples of programs that produce different output when compiled with C and C++ compilers?

Answer (score 1):

- `sizeof('c')` — 1 in C++, same as `sizeof(int)` in C.

Comment: That's not guaranteed to be different :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB: For those few systems where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(char)`, which necessitates `CHAR_BITS > 8`.